# an item with the same key has already been added mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I am trying to split the results from a string into a dictionary so I can add the numbers together.  This is information received from a texting api a client will text in an account + the amount they want to donate and multiple accounts are separated by commas ex th 20.00, bf 10.00 etc.

When I run the code it worked find in windows form's but when i converted over to MVC I get the error "an item with the same key has already been added" which i know means its duplicating an key.  I tried entering an if statement during the foreach loop:

```
    if(!tester.containsKey(j){}
```

but that did not always solve the problem and created a new error about out of range. Below is my current code:

```
    public ActionResult register(text2give reg)
    {
        string body = reg.body;
        try
        {
            var items = body.Split(',');

            Dictionary<string, float> tester = new Dictionary<string, float>();
            var j = 0;
            var total = 0f;
            while (j < body.Length)
            {

                foreach (var item in items)
                {

                    var s = item.Trim().Split(' ');
                    tester.Add(s[0], float.Parse(s[1]));
                    total += float.Parse(s[1]);
                    j++;

                }
            }
            ViewBag.total = total;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        return View(reg);
    }
```

Comment: Contents of `reg.body`?

Comment: Consider using `tester[]` rather than `tester.Add`

Comment: @splender it is what is received through the texting api.  the user is suppose to text in an donation which is formatted as where they want the donation to go and the amount  if they want to do multiple destinations the would seperate each one by a common.  example would be  reg.body = offering 20, building 15, youth 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s[0] is the duplicate key not j. You would need to use the following

```
var s = item.Trim().Split(' ');
if(!tester.containsKey(s[0]){
    tester.Add(s[0], float.Parse(s[1]));
    total += float.Parse(s[1]);
    j++;
}
```

You might be getting duplicate data, be careful ignoring the keys as you might actually need the data. I'm just showing you how to suppress the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is OK, but it makes quite a few assumptions:

- It assumes the body is split properly
- It assumes all items are unique (apparently they aren't, hence the error)
- It assumes there are two elements in each item (it isn't, hence the indexOutOfRangeException)

Here's how I would write this code to make sure it correctly guards against these cases:

```
public ActionResult register(text2give reg)
{
    string body = reg.body;
    try
    {
        var items = body.Split(',');
        var splitItems = items.Select(i => i.Split(' ')).ToList();

        var itemsWithTwoValues = splitItems.Where(s => s.Length == 2);

        var uniqueItems = itemsWithTwoValues.GroupBy(s => s[0])
                                            .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                                            .SelectMany(g => g);

        var tester = uniqueItems.ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => float.Parse(s[1]));

        var total = tester.Sum(s => s.Value);

        ViewBag.total = total;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    return View(reg);
}
```

Or, the shorter, condensed version:

```
public ActionResult register(text2give reg)
{
    string body = reg.body;
    try
    {
        var tester = body.Split(',')                            // Split the initial value into items
                         .Select(i => i.Split(' '))             // Split each item into elements
                         .Where(s => s.Length == 2)             // Take only those that have 2 items
                         .GroupBy(s => s[0])                    // Group by the key
                         .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)            // Remove all those that have a duplicate key
                         .SelectMany(g => g)                    // Ungroup them again
                         .ToDictionary(s => s[0], 
                                       s => float.Parse(s[1])); // Create a dictionary where the first item is the key and the second is the parsed float

        var total = tester.Sum(s => s.Value);

        ViewBag.total = total;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    return View(reg);
}
```

Comment: Just one thing to note - `float.Parse` could blow up if the client culture and server culture formats don't match. So, care will need to be taken to ensure that they are the same between client and server (possibly using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's also possible something completely different comes in. In that case you'd have to use `TryParse`

Comment: For some reason the code above is not adding the totals together it only pulls the first item in the reg.body.  i used the shortened one

Comment: Try debugging the code and see what the values in the dictionary are.

Comment: if i use the following get http://localhost:50545/text2give/register/?vaultid=txt5551234567&body=th%2020,%20bf%2020,%20ms%205  it only captures the first part of the body th 20